# How to erase while iterating boost::intrusive::list

Tags: c++, list, boost, boost-intrusive

How can I erase elements from a `boost::intrusive::list` while iterating through it?  The following code fails with an assertion failure https://wandbox.org/permlink/nzFshFSsaIrvBiTa

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Integer : public boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<> {
public:
    explicit Integer(int a_in) : a{a_in} {}
    int a;
};

int main() {
    auto vec = std::vector<Integer>{};
    vec.push_back(Integer{1});
    vec.push_back(Integer{2});
    vec.push_back(Integer{3});
    auto list = boost::intrusive::list<Integer>{};
    for (auto ele : vec) {
        list.push_back(ele);
    }

    for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end();) {
        if (it->a == 2) {
            it = list.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }

    for (auto ele : list) {
        cout << ele.a << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have pushed temporaries into the list:

```
for (auto ele : vec) {
    list.push_back(ele);
}
```

You probably meant to write:

```
for (auto& ele : vec) {
    list.push_back(ele);
}
```

This is *classic* confusion when starting to work with intrusive containers: nothing is by value like all the with all the standard library containers.

To avoid situations like this, consider using the auto-unlinking hook mode.

### Demo

Even safer than having to think about reference-qualifying the loop variable, is having no loop at all:

```
boost::intrusive::list<X> list(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/902c1de07755a8e7)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

struct X : public boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<> {
    X(int a_in) : a{a_in} {}
    int a;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, X const& x) { return os << "{" << x.a << "}"; }
};

int main() {
    std::ostream_iterator<X> out(std::cout << std::unitbuf, " ");

    std::vector<X> vec { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    boost::intrusive::list<X> list(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    std::cout << "before: "; std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), out);

    list.remove_if([](X const& x) { return 0 == (x.a % 2); });

    std::cout << "\nafter: "; std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), out);
}
```

Prints

```
before: {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9} {10} 
after: {1} {3} {5} {7} {9}
```

### With `auto_unlink`:

```
struct X : public bi::list_base_hook<bi::link_mode<bi::auto_unlink> > {
```

> *Note, you need to disable constant-time `size()` support for the `list<>`* (see [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/intrusive/auto_unlink_hooks.html#intrusive.auto_unlink_hooks.auto_unlink_and_constant_time))

With that in place, even adding

```
vec.erase(vec.begin()+4);
```

will correctly unlink the corresponding node from the intrusive list:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d02f28356dcd89f)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

namespace bi = boost::intrusive;

struct X : public bi::list_base_hook<bi::link_mode<bi::auto_unlink> > {
    X(int a_in) : a{a_in} {}
    int a;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, X const& x) { return os << "{" << x.a << "}"; }
};

int main() {
    std::ostream_iterator<X> out(std::cout << std::unitbuf, " ");

    std::vector<X> vec { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    bi::list<X, bi::constant_time_size<false> > list(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    std::cout << "before: "; std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), out);

    list.remove_if([](X const& x) { return 0 == (x.a % 2); });

    std::cout << "\nafter: "; std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), out);

    vec.erase(vec.begin()+4);
    std::cout << "\nauto-unlinked: "; std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), out);
}
```

Prints

```
before: {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9} {10} 
after: {1} {3} {5} {7} {9} 
auto-unlinked: {1} {3} {6} {8} {10}
```

Comment: Added demos with and without auto-unlink mode; also some stylistic tips

Comment: Uhhh *facepalm*

Comment: We've all been there. In good news, your question code was excellent. Clean, to the point and self-contained. Keep on slaying :)

Comment: Interesting construction of the `ostream_iterator`.  Can't upvote more than once lol but 